# VBA Error: "Run Time Error '424' Object required when attempting to .getElementById

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I continue to get the above error when running this code. I have tried dozens of web searches and adjustments to fix but unsuccessful. The code is below and any help if very much appreciated.

```
Public Sub Tagg()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'MICROSOFT Internet Controls (shdocvw.dll)
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim loginFrame As HTMLIFrame
    Dim usernameInput As HTMLInputElement, passwordInput As HTMLInputElement
    Dim username As String, password As String

    username = "MTorres" 'CHANGE THIS
    password = "melissa1" 'CHANGE THIS
    URL = "https://webaccess.tagglogistics.com/cadence/webaccess.net?action=203&Full=Y&args=415878"

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set loginFrame = .document.getElementById("loginframe")  ' ****ERROR HERE****
        Set HTMLdoc = loginFrame.contentWindow.document

         '<input name="username" id="uname" class="ti" maxlength="32" onchange="setUserValue();"
         'onkeydown="setupUserValue(event);" onmouseup="return false;" onclick="SelectAll();" onfocus="SelectAll();"
         'aria-describedby="cof_username errormsg" type="text">

        Set usernameInput = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("username")(0)
        usernameInput.Focus
        DoEvents
        usernameInput.Value = username
        usernameInput.FireEvent "onkeydown"
        usernameInput.FireEvent "onchange"
        usernameInput.FireEvent "onmouseup"

         '<input id="cofisso_ti_passw" name="password" class="ti" maxlength="32" aria-describedby="pass" type="password">

        Set passwordInput = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("password")(0)
        passwordInput.Focus
        passwordInput.Value = password

         'HTMLdoc.forms(0).submit
         '<input src="/resources/images/btn_login.gif" alt="Login" title="Login" name="cofisso_btn_login" id="cofisso_btn_login" type="image">
        HTMLdoc.getElementById("cofisso_btn_login").Click
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

         '----------- NEW CODE --------------

         'Might need this wait loop
        While .document.readyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
        Wend

         'Either reload HTMLdoc from current IE.document:
        Set HTMLdoc = .document

         'Or if LNKLOGOUT is inside an iframe:
         '        Dim iframe As HTMLIFrame
         '        Set iframe = .document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")(0)        '0 = 1st iframe
         '        Set HTMLdoc = iframe.contentWindow.document

         'HTMLdoc should now be available here - display webpage TEXT TO verify

        MsgBox HTMLdoc.body.innerText

         '---------- END OF NEW CODE ----------

         'Click "Sign Out" link
         '<a id="LNKLOGOUT" class="logout" href="https://servicing.capitalone.com/C1/SelfService/CMLogoutIntercept.aspx">Sign Out</a>
        HTMLdoc.getElementById("LNKLOGOUT").Click
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure `.document` is not `nothing`?

Comment: Which line in the VBA does the error occur? To find out, click `debug' on the error message, and the line causing the problem will be highlighted.

Comment: There is already a comment in the code indicating where the error occurs.

Comment: If `MTorres` and `melissa1` are valid credentials, I suggest you change them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**[CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):**

You could have shortened most of that by using CSS selectors to target the elements of interest.

The selectors are:

1. `input[name='LoginID']`
2. `input[name='Password']`
3. `input[type='image']`

These says select elements with `input` tag having attribute `name` or `type`,  with value of `'Login'` or `'Password'` or `'image'` respectively. "[]" is the selector for attribute.

---

**VBA:**

You apply CSS selectors with [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document`:

```
.document.querySelector("input[name='LoginID']").Value = USERNAME
.document.querySelector("input[name='Password']").Value = PASSWORD
.document.querySelector("input[type='image']").Click
```

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Tagg()
    Dim URL As String, ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Const USERNAME As String = "MTorres"
    Const PASSWORD As String = "melissa1"
    URL = "https://webaccess.tagglogistics.com/cadence/webaccess.net?action=203&Full=Y&args=415878"

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .document.querySelector("input[name='LoginID']").Value = USERNAME
        .document.querySelector("input[name='Password']").Value = PASSWORD
        .document.querySelector("input[type='image']").Click

        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set HTMLdoc = .document
        'Other code
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the document and loginframe correctly.

Replace these lines:

```
Set loginFrame = .document.getElementById("loginframe")  ' ****ERROR HERE****
Set HTMLdoc = loginFrame.contentWindow.document
```

With these:

```
Set HTMLdoc = ie.Document
Set loginFrame = HTMLdoc.getElementById("loginframe")  ' ****ERROR FIXED****
```

You'll get another error a few lines down when you try to find an element with the name "username" because there is no such element on that page, but hopefully this will get you on the right track.